# What solutions are available for having a client boot straight into a Windows VDI?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, thin-client, scvmm, vdi

I don't have much experience with enterprise level Virtual Desktop management (yet). I'm looking for a Microsoft solution if one exists, but all valid answers would be appreciated.

The scenario is this: How would one setup a workstation to either

1) Boot up and automatically download an advertised virtual desktop

2) Boot up to something like [Windows Thin PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/virtualization/thinpc.aspx), then once the user authenticates they are taken to a virtual desktop.

3) A similar process

For #2, I thought about changing the user's shell via group policy from explorer.exe to a command line (if one existed) that loads a virtual desktop. If not using TPC the user would have to authenticate against our ad somehow, and these machines aren't open to all authenticated users, so the client has to have that capability.

My goal is to boot the user into an available VD from a pool of VDs, as seamless as possible. Having them login to Windows then double click an icon is a huge seam. At some point they have to authenticate so that's a hard requirement.

I saw a (very) brief demonstration of VMWare View, but I'm not sure if it will do what I'm asking above.

We're also licensed for SCVMM, and from a [brief read of a blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vishwa/archive/2011/02/01/tuning-scvmm-for-vdi-deployments.aspx), that might be leverage-able.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you Citrix XenDesktop. XenDesktop can help you with your goals.

https://www.citrix.com/products/xendesktop/overview.html